How to subscribe to calendars so they are synced to all devices?
If I subscribe to a calendar in the iOS calendar app, it is only visible on that device:

However, in the past I’ve been able to add a calendar subscription to my iCloud account so it syncs across all devices:

I can’t see for the life of me how I did this. I think it was from the settings app but I can’t find the option on my iPhone (iOS 18) or iPad (iPadOS 17). I’ve read I can do it from a Mac, but I don’t own a Mac so I know I never did it that way.
How can I add a subscription so it’s synced to all my devices?

Not sure, but have you checked in the Settings of the iPhone and made iCloud your "default" calendar? Also, try subscribing via Settings > Apps > Calendar > Accounts > Add Account > Other > Subscribed Calendar. That flow may be different than adding directly from the Calendar app itself.

@luckman212 First question: yes, it is. Second question: now, with a gun to my head I’d have said this is exactly the way I did it before to add them to my iCloud account. However, that isn’t working and they end up under “subscribed calendars” and only on the device I do it. So, it’s possible the behaviour has changed, I suppose.
